# MonoDevelop crashes on each error

Tags: .net, winforms, mono, crash, ubuntu-14.04

```
OS : Ubuntu 14.04.01
MonoDevelop
Version 4.0.12
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.8 
    GTK 2.24.23
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
```

I am using monodevelop for C# winform application. The application is developed in Visual Studio 2013, C#, winform, .net framework 4.0.

Now i am porting this application in mono so that it can run on Ubuntu. But it seems mono is not much compitble for winform.

My problem is mono develop is crashing each time when any error occurs. I don't know what is wrong. I need to know, is there any setting or configuration that can stop it to be crashed or any update is available for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution.

Monodevelop has functionality that you can specify which exception MonoDevelop should throw.

For this we need to specify exceptions which we want to be handled with it.

Go to Run -> Exceptions (the last option)

Select all exceptions (or the exceptions that you want to throw) press right arrow button and click on "ok". 
Hope this will work.

It is a bug, because in any case MonoDevelop should not stop execution. It can throw error in that case.